# Oracle rowid in where clause results in high optimizer cost on new Oracle 12c install

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, rowid

I'm hoping the community here can help me out with an interesting issue we've seen while moving from Oracle 11g to Oracle 12c.

We have a query that is executed by Informatica PowerCenter that was taking a long time after our upgrade to 12c.  Research showed the execution plan was different between 11g and 12c.  We updated table and index statistics and it didn't help.  We traced the culprit down to a `WHERE` clause that refers to `ROWID`.

This is quite abbreviated, but the beef of the query that was causing the issue looked like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT t1.*,
               FIRST_VALUE(rowid) OVER (PARTITION BY c1, c2
                                            ORDER BY DECODE(c3, 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'Z'), c3 DESC) AS max_rowid
          FROM t1)
 WHERE max_rowid <> rowid
```

I changed the query to use the `RANK` analytic function instead of `FIRST_VALUE` and all is well.  The cost went from in the millions to tens of thousands.

Any thougths on what could cause this?  Thanks much for your thoughts in advance.

Comment: Only difference that hops to mind is that FIRST_VALUE returns the values themselves for comparison, wheras RANK returns a number for integer comparison, but I'm surprised if that alone would make that much difference. Did you also change the partition or order clauses?.

Comment: I would double check the C3 column and the returned data set in the modified query. As Michael Broughton mentioned above, RANK() returns a number, and by its definition it could be returning ties, therefore changing your result set. Row_number() on the other hand does not allow ties. As for you question, First_value does require an argument while rank, dense_rank or row_number don't, that might make a difference for the optimizer when choosing.

Comment: Please edit your question and include both execution plans.

Comment: There is no problem with rowid in 12c, this is for sure. The optimizer is different, the data dictionary is different, etc, so the plan may be different. You always will get "distorted" plans when moving to another version.